# Problems running rails db:migrate with rolify

Tags: r, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify

Currently trying to install rolify to my rails application

Followed the steps on github and am getting the following error after running rails db:migrate

```
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rolify-5.2.0/lib/rolify.rb:30: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1826: warning: The called method `has_and_belongs_to_many' is defined here
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `Migration' for ActiveRecord:Module
/mnt/d/linux-docs/projects/code/rails/kream/kream/src/db/migrate/20200511073629_rolify_create_roles.rb:1:in `<main>'

Caused by:
NoMethodError: undefined method `Migration' for ActiveRecord:Module
/mnt/d/linux-docs/projects/code/rails/kream/kream/src/db/migrate/20200511073629_rolify_create_roles.rb:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the migration file ammend the version number like so

```
class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table(:roles) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table(:users_roles, :id => false) do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :role
    end

    add_index(:roles, [ :name, :resource_type, :resource_id ])
    add_index(:users_roles, [ :user_id, :role_id ])
  end
end
```